# Custom Shareholder Value function in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I've become very interested in creating custom functions in Excel using VBA lately, because custom functions can save tremendous amounts of time. As I a used to Java and not VBA, I'm currently having a little trouble with some operators (such as the lack of += ) and Arrays.

However, my latest function, which is a little more complex than the ones I previously created, doesn't want to work.

The functions goal is to calculate the Shareholder Value, given both a Cash-Inflow and Cash-Outflow as Range, interest rates and the equity ratio.

So what the function is supposed to do is:

1. Calculate all relevant variables (WACC etc)
2. Calculate the sum of the discounted Cashflows (In- and Outflow) from the Range-Objecs
3. Calculate the Shareholder Value with using the previously calculated variables

My Code:

```
    Function SHV(CashInflow As Range, CashOutflow As Range, EKZins As Double, FKZins As Double, EKQuote As Double)

Dim DCIF As Double
Dim DCOF As Double
Dim FKQ As Double
Dim FKZ As Double
Dim FKZF As Double
Dim EKZF As Double
Dim GKZ As Double
Dim GKZF As Double
Dim ER As Double
Dim RV As Double

Dim n As Integer
Dim i As Integer


    DCIF = 0
    DCOF = 0
    FKQ = 1 - EKQuote
    FKZF = 1 + FKZins
    EKZF = 1 + EKZins
    GKZ = (FKQ * FKZins + EKQuote * EKZins) / (FKQ / EKQuote)
    GKZF = GKZ + 1
    n = CashInflow.Count

        For i = 1 To n

            DCIF = DCIF + ((CashInflow(CashInflow.Row, i) * GKZF ^ i))
            DCOF = DCOF + ((CashOutflow(CashOutflow.Row, i) * FKZF ^ i))

        Next i

    ER = CashInflow(CashInflow.Row, n) / GKZ
    RV = CashOutflow(CashOutflow.Row, n) / FKZ

    SHV = (DCIF + ER) - (DCOF + RV)

End Function
```

I hope somebody will be able to help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please define "just doesn't work".  An error?  Please take a moment to check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) as well as [ask].

Comment: On second look, that's **a lot** of undeclared variables.  At the very top of the module, add the line `Option Explicit'.  This will force an error for any undeclared variable.  Also, without sample input data (and knowing what the Function's output is supposed to be), it's extremely difficult to troubleshoot.  Good luck :)